# One word to describe all flora

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I'm looking for a single word that describes all flowers, plants, trees and grass?

Comment: *Flora* is the word that you are looking for. HTH

Comment: Do you mean to exclude fungus?

Comment: *Vegetation* might work. I assume OP doesn't really want to get bogged down in the potential distinction between ***gut flora*** and ***gut fauna*** in the intestinal tract, or whether *fungi* are "plants".

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is in the title: *flora*, according to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flora?s=t) defined as:

> the plants of a particular region or period, listed by species and considered as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

*Plant life*, possibly?

> **plant life** noun
>
> all plants, taken as a whole
>
> - Cacti are the most intelligent form of plant life on the planet.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plant-life)

Answer (score 0):

**plant kingdom** includes all the forms you mention.

> [plant kingdom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plant_kingdom) - Collectively, the set of all plants.

**vegetable kingdom** is another name for "plant kingdom" which, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vegetable-kingdom), is not current usage anymore.